# FileSystemWatcher and design patterns

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, filesystems

im trying to build an app that watches lots of directories with FileSystemWatcher and notifies a search engine if something changes. Should I create a new FileSystemWatcher for each directory? Should I apply an spesific design pattern? I need some help with the desing of the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To minimize the number of `FileSystemWatcher` objects, you can leverage the properties of the `FileSystemWatcher` class:

- `IncludeSubdirectories` - set this to `true` if you want to monitor every single subdirectory within a directory. So instead of creating a dedicated watcher for each child, you will use only one watcher for the parent directory.
- `NotifyFilter` - use this to limit the scope of watched files (e.g., if you only want to detect changes to `*.txt` files (or something else, there's a lot of options).
- `InternalBuffer` - you can adjust this property to find balance between verbosity and memory consumption.

If there's a specific limited list of folders to watch for, then I guess it's OK to use a separate watcher for each of them.
How many folders do you typically expect to be monitored?

Comment: Hi! Im planning to index lots of files for lots of different directories in different location (not only sub direcotries).
The app is for a search engine and im planning to create a new filesystemwatcher for each directory. Any idea of how to group them and watch their events?

Comment: A couple of years ago, I have developed a similar app. It had different 'trace profiles' (collections of watched folders) stored in the DB, and the server would read the profile from the DB and create `FileSystemWatcher` objects for each folder in that profile. I don't have the source code currently, but I remember that I created all watchers in one method (on server startup), and used the same event handlers for each watcher. So, I had hundreds of watchers, but only 4 handler methods (Created, Renamed, Changed, Deleted) and the concrete watcher could be determined from the `sender` argument.

Comment: Cool, that is what im talking about. Where did used put the filesystemwatcher? in a class? on a list?

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember when trying to use `FileSystemWatcher` it is lacking on being able to filter in a way that was useful, at least for me. I think I ended up having to create a `FileSystemWatcher` for each extension of file I wanted to watch.  Also depending on what changes you are watching for, `FileSystemWatcher` throws a lot of events, some seem like they are double.  But if you are looking for just created I don't think that will be an issue.

I did find that the RX extensions worked very well for helping filter out what I needed.  This page has an example. http://www.developerit.com/2010/04/20/reactive-extensions-vs-`FileSystemWatcher`

I'd probably create a `FileSystemWatcher` for each type of change or file you are trying to watch.  If it is everything then one will probably suffice.